# Difference in newlines in output between awk's printf and sprintf

Tags: awk

Gawk manual [says](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) about sprintf: "Return (without printing) the string that printf would have printed out..."

Here is the printf output:

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0 }' <<< 'line1
line2'
line1line2%
```

However, sprintf seems to preserve newlines:

```
awk '{ my_var=sprintf("%s", $0); print my_var }' <<< 'line1
line2'
line1
line2
```

(The same with BSD and GNU awk.)

Why is it so?

How do I put in a variable the newline-stripped content this way, without using RS/ORS/sub?

Comment: `print` prints the newline. You are doing `my_var=soemthing; print` `How do I put in a variable the newline-stripped content this way` It's in `$0`, if you don't want to print a newline, print it with `printf`. `printf "%s", my_var`

Comment: @KamilCuk , if the variable were single-line, the following command, I suppose, should print both lines as one line. Note that there is no `print`. It is not the case, though. `awk '/line1/,/line2/ { out=sprintf("%s", $0); match(out, /line1.*/); print out }' <<< 'line1 \
line2'`

Comment: `print out` _prints the newline_. `print` prints the arguments _plus a newline_. `awk '/line1/,/line2/ { out=sprintf("%s", $0); match(out, /line1.*/); printf out }' <<<$'line1 \\\nline2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feed awk (2 records of) data with a newline in the middle, ie.:

```
<<<'line1
line2'
```

awk is going to process the input record by record (notice the `NR` in code, don't mind the `()` after `printf`:

```
$ awk '{ printf("%s %s", NR, $0) }' <<< 'line1
line2'
1 line12 line2$
```

or

```
$ awk '{ print sprintf("%s %s", NR, $0) }' <<< 'line1
line2'
1 line1
2 line2
$
```

In the former `printf` didn't produce newline after either of the records, in the latter `print` did.

If you want to preserve the newline (between records), read the whole data in at once without processing the newlines (well, this does involve using `RS`):

```
$ awk -v RS="^$" '{ printf("%s %s", NR, $0) }' <<< 'line1
line2'
1 line1
line2
$
```

If you are unable to use the `RS`, you need to parse the input yourself. Sample data, `cat file`:

```
line1
line2 \\
line3 \
line4
line5
```

`\` marks to attach 2 records, `\\` is a backslash:

```
$ awk '{
    if(/[^\\]\\$/) {                      # if ends in one \
       b=b substr($0,1,length($0)-1) ORS  # append to buffer b
       next                               # on to next record
    }
    $0=b $0                               # prepend buffer to record
    gsub(/\\\\/,"\\")                     # \\s to \s
    print sprintf("%s %s", ++c, $0)       # output, NR replace with c 
    b=""                                  # empty the buffer
}' file
```

Output:

```
1 line1
2 line2 \
3 line3 
line4
4 line5
```

Answer (score 2):

**If You Want To Remove the** `'\n'`

If you want to strip the newline, then `sed` makes that easy:

```
$ sed '/[\]/{N;s/\n//}' <<< 'line1 \
line2'
line1 \line2
```

Or you can use `awk` as:

```
$ awk '/\\$/ {line = line $0; next} { print line $0; line = ""}' <<< 'line1 \
line2'
line1 \line2
```

Where you simply concatenate lines ending in `\` and then output all of the concatenated lines along with the current line for the first line not ending in `'\'` and reset the variable you are accumulating the lines in (`line` above).

You can handle trailing whitespace between the `'\'` and end of line by adding `/\\[[:blank:]]*$/` to your Regex.

Let me know if I missed your intent and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: David C. Rankin ,thanks, but I need it in a variable to pass to match(), otherwise I would easily use `print` (as you kindly suggested) or `printf`. There could also be no backslashes in the actual content at the end of a line. Sed is no option, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. If there is no `'\'` at the end of the line -- how do you know which lines you want to join and which lines to leave as separate lines? For the variable, you can pass from the shell into `awk` with `awk -v var="$shellvar" '{...}'` which will make the awk variable `var` hold the contents of what was `"$shellvar"` in your shell. Let me know on how to identify which lines to join. If you just want the entire line in a variable in awk, `myvar = $0` works fine (like I used `line` in my example)

Comment: Also, when you say "I need it in a variable", what is "it" you want to capture? The whole record or just the last field in the record? If the last field (like the `'\'`), you can just use `myvar = $NF` to capture whatever the last field is. If that will make the number of fields numerically one-more-than the lines you don't join, then you have `NF` as the key to use to make that determination.

Comment: Here is (a bit simplified) real code, which should return `line` (backslashes as a visual clue that there is a newline): `awk '/line1/,/line2/ { out=sprintf("%s", $0); match(out, /line1.*line2/); out=substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-12); print out }' <<< 'line1 \
line \
line2'` I also cannot change RS/ORS.

Comment: With `"'line1\nline\nline2"` as your input, what is your desired output. That's where I'm still a bit hazy on where we are going. At first I just thought you wanted to remove the `\n'` after each line-continuation `'\'`, but now I suspect you are after something else. So if I have the input lines right -- what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I want everything between "line1" and "line2", squeezed in one line, whether it is originally a single line or many lines.

Comment: Okay, you were saying that with your range-expression of `line1/, /line2/`. So we are just getting rid of `line`, be it one-or-many lines that fall between `line1` and `line2` and will then combine the first and last record in that set (with perhaps a few modifications) for the final output for that range. i'll be back in a couple of hours, eyes must close before the sun rises.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `sprintf seems to preserve newlines` - no, awk consumes the newline when it reads the record. In:

```
awk '{ my_var=sprintf("%s", $0); print my_var }' <<< 'line1
line2'
```

`$0` never contains a newline and so the output of that `sprintf` doesn't contain a newline. The `print` command **adds** a newline when outputting `my_var`. If you did:

```
print "<" my_var ">"
```

then you'd see that `my_var` doesn't contain a newline, the newline appears after the `>`, not before it.

I'm saying `newline` above but it's really whatever value `RS` has on input and `ORS` on output, they're both just newline by default.

Regarding `How do I put in a variable the newline-stripped content this way` - that's already what it contains. If you want `my_var` to then be output without a newline being appended then do either this:

```
printf "%s", my_var
```

or this:

```
ORS=""; ...; print my_var
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I put in a variable the newline-stripped content this way,
> without using RS/ORS/sub?

Use `sprintf` return value(s) as argument(s) to `printf`, consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
12.12 14.14 16.16
```

then

```
awk '{x=sprintf("%d",$1);y=sprintf("%d",$2);z=sprintf("%d",$3)}END{printf "%s%s%s",x,y,z}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
121416
```

(without trailing newline)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

if u just wanna concat it all without `\n` :

> ```
> % jot 30 | mawk _^_ ORS=
> ```

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930%  # "...%" = no trailing \n
```

To add back 1 more trailing newline, it's easier via the pipe :

> ```
> jot 30 | gawk // ORS= | nawk $$
> ```

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930
```

another way to add back the trailing new line while stripping all input inewlines would be like :

> ```
> mawk2 ++NF OFS= RS= FS='\412'
> ```

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930
```

if u wanna convert vertical input to horizontal :

> ```
> nawk NF=NF FS='\n' RS=
> ```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

horizontal ***without*** trailing newline :

> ```
> gawk 8 ORS=' '
> ```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30%
```